# how to generate report for attendance system

Tags: mysql

hello i have to create a attendance management system and for that i need to generate a report i.e the report which would contain the average of a students subject wise and overall attendance the table which are created are:

```
    create table faculty(id int(10),faculty_id int(10));
     create table subject(id int(10),subject_id int(10),subject_name varchar(10));
       create table attendance(id int(10),enrollment_no int(10),attendance int(10));
        create table branch(id int(10),branch_id int(10),branch_name varchar(10));
```

so from the above four tables i need to generate the report for the attendance so i an unable to generate it so anybody could please help.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question is not specific enough to get any help. What have you got so far, what do you want to achieve, what programming language do you want to use, how shall the output be generated etc. etc.

If all that makes no sense to you, you might want to learn MySQL from the beginnings. The key words are "select" and "join".

Once you can generate the result you need, MySQLAdmin/ PhpMyAdmin offers some "export to excel" functionality.